# I don't understand this sentence grammatically

Tags: grammar

I saw this title while watching youtube

> "TF Blade Gets EVERY Western Streamer Banned in Korea"

(TF Blade is streamer)

As far as i understand, "Every Western Streamer were banned in korea" and "TF Blade Gets them", but translator says that meaning of this sentence is "TF Blade made them banned"

Should this be understood as

> "TF Blade gets every Western Streamer to be banned in Korea"

I want to know what is difference between two sentences and why these sentences are grammatically correct. (Are there any omitted parts?)

I would appreciate it if you could explain it easily and in detail

Comment: 2nd one is correct.

Comment: _Gets_ here means _causes to be_ - it causes Korea to ban every Western streamer. (Proofreading - "Is this correct?" - is off-topic, but both _I_ and _Korea_ need a capital letter.)

Answer (score 3):

The sense of "gets", in this sentence is "causes to happen or become; brings about" ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get#:%7E:text=to%20cause%20something%20to%20happen%2C%20or%20cause%20someone%20or%20something%20to%20do%20something%3A))

So the meaning here is the TF Blade causes every Western streamer to become banned.

while there is a syntactic ambiguity, the alternate meaning "TF Blade receives all the western streamers that are banned in Korea" is impossible (without lots of ad-hoc assumptions) and so rejected.

I note the capitalisation, this suggests that this is a headline, which justifies the use of simple present tense.  In normal text, the present perfect or past tense might be better "TF Blade got (has got/has gotten) every western streamer banned."

Regarding the use of an infinitive "gets ... to be banned".  This is also possible but unidiomatic.  If you want to use a verb phrase, the the infinitive is needed "I got him to play tennis".  But there is no need for a full passive voice in the infinitive, as the participle (or participle adjective) is correct.  That is "got him banned" is preferred to "got him to be banned".

Answer (score 0):

**Without further context the sentence is ambiguous because of the capitals**

**Context 1**
If *Western Streamer* is the name of a publication (or of a series of videos by a particular streamer), then TF Blade could get (obtain) a copy of that publication or video, even if it had been banned in Korea.

**Context 2**
However, if we are discussing western people who are streamers, it is clear that these people's channels are being banned owing to the actions of TF Blade.

Of course we can guess that one or the other is intended, but the grammar is entirely ambiguous. (see note)

> "TF Blade Gets EVERY Western Streamer Banned in Korea"

1. TF Blade obtains every *Western Streamer* that has been banned in Korea (correct)
2. TF Blade ensures that every western streamer becomes banned in Korea (correct)

---

**Important grammar note**

Capital letters affect the meaning. There is a difference between

"TF Blade gets every western streamer banned in Korea"

and

"TF Blade gets every Western Streamer banned in Korea"

Your test capitalised everything, so it is impossible to tell.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence implies that some action of "TF Streamer" provoked authorities in Korea to ban, not only "TF Streamer," but also *all other Western streamers.*

TF Streamer did not ban anyone.  What TF Streamer did caused others to also be banned.  This is why the verb is "gets ... banned" (two-word separable verb).  Notice that "gets" is *singular*, applying to a singular subject.